# Cannot execute PHP script periodically using crontab on Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, scheduled-tasks, cron

I want to execute a php script every 5 minutes. I'm using Ubuntu and I followed these steps:

Executed `crontab -e` from terminal, entered:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php  /var/www/test1.php
```

in the nano text editor, saved it and started the crontab. It gave no errors and said "installing new crontab", but my script is not being executed. I gave the necessary permissions to the files I use in my script, too.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you checked `php5-cli` installed?

Comment: Yes, the newest version...

Comment: Try to `php5 /var/www/test1.php` at first from CL, if everything will be ok, move it to crontab. I use Ubuntu and `php5` works for me in crontab. And what's going if You call `/usr/bin/php /var/www/test1.php` from Your CL, is script working?

Comment: I called `/usr/bin/php /var/www/test1.php` on CL and it worked...

Comment: shouldn't it be `php -f /path/to/file.php`?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use for scheduling cron jobs on apache server in cpanel interface :

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/domain_name/public_html/cron_test.php
```

So, you should specify the path to the php executable too, for making the php script work and execute.

Comment: He did it without `quiet` flag, doesn't he?